# Mobius function and Euler Product Triangle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Gevorg Hmayakyan proposed last year (17 September 2017) on StackExchange the following relationship concerning the mobius function. Gevorg stated that if
$$∏^{n−1}_{i=1}(1−x^i)=∑_{k=0}^{n(n−1)/2}a_{n,k}x^{k} $$
then
$$μ(n)=a_{n,1}+a_{n,n+1}+a_{n,2n+1}+a_{n,3n+1}+...$$

Does anyone know how prove this?

During related computer computation on this function, I also noted that
$$\phi (n)=a_{n,0}+a_{n,n}+a_{n,2n}+a_{n,3n}+...$$

but why this is the case I do not know? Any insights?

PS. I had noticed that the above generating function is equivalent to a row of Euler Truncated Product Triangle (see the paper by Alex Mennen at http://www.alex.mennen.org/mahoniantri.pdf). Thus
Using Mennens notation then they become
$$μ(n)=∑_{k=0}^{n(n−1)/2}P(n−2,kn+1)$$
$$\phi(n)=∑_{k=0}^{n(n−1)/2}P(n−2,kn)$$

Comment: Hello this may be useful: https://oeis.org/w/images/9/93/Moebius_and_Totient.pdf

Comment: Thanks Gevorg.  From a programming perspective, the approach suffers from integer overflow and memory constraints O(n^2). The integer overflow can be overcome by using modular arithmetric e.g. for Mobius use mod 4, for Totient use mod n.  The memory can be theoretical reduced to the order O(n) but with the tradeoff with processing time.

Answer (score 5):

For $\phi(n)$, series multisection means that
$$\sum_{k}a_{n,kn}x^{kn}=\frac1n \sum_{j=0}^n f_n(\zeta^j x)$$
where $f_n(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-x^i)$ and $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$. Therefore
$$\sum_{k}a_{n,kn}=\frac1n \sum_{j=0}^n f_n(\zeta^j).$$
If $\gcd(j,n)>1$ then $f_n(\zeta^j)=0$. For $\gcd(j,n)=1$ then
$f_n(\zeta^j)=f_n(\zeta)=\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(1-\zeta_j)$ and so
$$\sum_{k}a_{n,kn}=\frac{\phi(n)}n f_n(\zeta).$$
But
$$f_n(\zeta)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)\cdots(x-\zeta^{n-1})}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=n.$$
We conclude $$\sum_{k}a_{n,kn}=\phi(n).$$

ADDED IN EDIT

The $\mu(n)$ case follows similar lines. In this case
$$\sum_{k}a_{n,kn+1}=\frac1n \sum_{j=0}^n\zeta^{-j} f_n(\zeta^j).$$
This reduces to $\sum_{j:gcd(n,j)=1}\zeta^{-j}$. This is the
sum of all primitive $n$-th roots of unity, which is $\mu(n)$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It will take me awhile to understand, as it is bit above my pay grade. Can this be generalised to $a_{kn +j}$?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you "Lord Shark the Unknown". What an elegant answer. Since then I have done some further research based on your answer in relation to the general case. I deduced from Wikipedia that these are related to Ramujanim Sums.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n(n-1)/2}a_{n,kn+j} = c_n(j) =\mu (\frac{n}{(n,j)})\frac{\phi (n)}{\phi (\frac{n}{n,j})}$$